# how to declare viewstate in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

May i know how to declare  viewstate..
what i need is sql  some data is exists 
So, i want to create  data table columns and  fill the data.
and i want to save it in view state 
but viewstate i am not able to declare  showing some error 
have a look on below iamge..
any solution
exactly at viewsate  showing message if i put mouse on viewsate
it is telling declaration is expected..

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SNO", GetType(String)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Standard Description", GetType(String)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ItemCode", GetType(String)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Regional Name", GetType(String)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("UOM", GetType(String)))


        For i As Integer = 1 To RS1.RecordCount
            dr = dt.NewRow()

            dr("SNO") = i
            dr("Standard Description") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmDes").Value
            dr("ItemCode") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmCde").Value
            dr("Regional Name") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmNme").Value
            dr("UOM") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_UOM").Value
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            RS1.MoveNext()
        Next
        ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
```

Comment: Viewstate as such is for ASP.Net for what I know, in VB.Net, placing it like ViewState(), will seek for a method by the name of Viewstate. For more details, check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State)

Comment: Why `viewstate` in the first place?

Comment: Are we talking about a VB.NET application or an ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 0):

```
   For i As Integer = 1 To RS1.RecordCount
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("SNO") = i
        dr("Standard Description") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmDes").Value
        dr("ItemCode") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmCde").Value
        dr("Regional Name") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmNme").Value
        dr("UOM") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_UOM").Value
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        RS1.MoveNext()
    Next
```

Commite this code and try to build again. If still getting this error. If not then there is problem in this code which is committed

Comment: hi..I think may u have not understood my problem

Comment: i am not able to declare view state..  view state is telling some error not at the time of running before running is all so  error